# ROS not working when Home directory is renamed

Tags: ros, ros-electric, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using ROS Electric on Fedora 14.

I have changed my home directory name from A to B by editing the /etc/passwd file and moving the files to the new directory (mv /home/A /home/B).

Now, i'm not able to work on ROS as the system is not able to launch ROS.
Naturally, some path of ROS still points to the old home name (A).
Can someone tell me where all i need to rename the path (from A to B) so that ROS works fine ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38053/ros-not-working-when-home-directory-is-renamed/) by [Subbu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2779/subbu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have compiled packages in the old location, run `make clean` to regenerate the `cmake` files.

EDIT: To regenerate a list of packages and all their dependencies, run:

```
rosmake --pre-clean package_name1 package_name2
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you used rosws / rosinstall, check the setup.sh in your workspace for reference to the old name at the top.
It is also possible to run

```
$ rosws regenerate
```

in your workspace for that purpose.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3